# Custom Perl target location with Module::Build

Tags: perl, module-build

I've customized a `Module::Build` script to install files from a `perllib/` directory in my sandbox to `perl/` in the target directory.

```
# Install perllib
$build->add_build_element("perllib");
$build->install_path(perllib => "$install_base/perl");
```

When I run `./Build test`, Perl can't find the files under `blib/` because it doesn't know that that these `perllib` files belong on `@INC`.

Is it possible to add the custom `perllib` directory to the installation, in such a way that the build system understands that they're Perl files, which should be included when we run tests?

Comment: What is the goal of keeping these files separate from the `lib` directory?

Comment: It's to conform with a custom system that we've been using to manage multiple installations. Eventually, I'd like to update it to use more a more standard installation tree, but so far it's been easier to update the build scripts.

Comment: Oh, can I keep a more standard sandbox to fix my testing issue, and somehow coerce Module::Build to install it in a non-standard place?

Comment: `PERL_MB_OPT` env var to tell M::B where to install it, and `PERL5LIB` to tell Perl where to look.

Comment: `PERL5LIB` has been my testing workaround.. I figure M::B should be able to figure it out on it's own though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a good reason to keep this `perllib/` directory in the module. I renamed it to `lib/` and customized its installation location.

```
my $build = Module::Build->new();
$build->install_base_relpaths(lib => 'perl');
```